# Is this group abelian?

Tags: group-theory

I tried to show that the following group is abelian by manipulation the relations but they didn't work. Please show me the right way. The group is $$G:=\left<x,y \mid xyxy^2=yxyx^2=1\right>$$

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Yea abelian @NancyR

Comment: Does the notation above mean 'for every pair, is is true that ...' or 'for every pair of distinct elements ...' ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

HINT:  From $xyxy^2 = 1$, you get $xyx = y^{-2}$.  Try substituting this into $yxyx^2 = 1$.

Comment: Excellent hint/answer. +1

Answer (score 14):

Sorry for this kind of answer. @Tara's hint is enough but mine is base on Van Kampen diagram.

[image]

Comment: Rats, also this one is nice though not so elementary as Tara's...+1

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks Don. I really ouldn't draw so I arranged it on a paper and this is one of my paintings. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Very nice! ++++

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** You can identify $xyxy^2$ as a subword of $yxyx^2$. In details:

> $$\begin{array}{ll} yxyx^2=1 & \Rightarrow xyxyx^2=x \\ & \Rightarrow (xyxy^2)y^{-1}x^2=x \\ & \Rightarrow y^{-1}x^2=x \\ & \Rightarrow y^{-1}x=1 \\ & \Rightarrow x=y \end{array}$$

So $G \simeq \langle x \mid x^5=1 \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: Noooo!  Please please please don't provide full answers to questions where someone (especially me =] ) has given a nice little hint, and the answer with the hint has been accepted.  It spoils all the fun.

Comment: OK, now I don't mind. =]  Thanks!

Comment: it's not so bad, Tara. In fact, your hint is almost a complete answer as it follows from it at once that the group is cyclic (and generated by $\,x\,$)...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yeah, I know.  I've just had this happen quite a few times, sometimes when there was a little more to do.  This wouldn't have bothered me much if hadn't been for those other times.

Comment: @TaraB: I always like this kind of answer. I remembered I saw it for the first time done by Brian. It really help the OP reflect about hints. But as always, Mouse can't wait not to move on gray area and... ;-)

Comment: @BabakS.:  You mean answers with a 'spoiler' box?  Seirios added that after I complained.  I think it's good too.  I only found out you could do that when someone suggested I use it in an answer on the computer science site.  It doesn't seem to be used as much here.

Comment: @Seirios:  How about you make the spoiler box not include the first line of your answer?  That way it can be partially a 'hint' answer, too.

Comment: @TaraB: Yes. I saw that before and after you did. Nice job Seirios. +1

Comment: @Seirios:  Sorry, far too many comments here now, but I just noticed that you seem to have multiplied both sides by $x$ for no particular reason.  You don't actually ever use that extra $x$.  So you could shorten your proof by two lines without it.

Comment: @TaraB: Thank for your comments, I improved my answer.

Comment: @Seirios:  Oh, I'm sorry.  I thought I was probably being stupid (I'm quite tired today), and now that you've edited your answer, I see where you used the extra $x$ before and I actually like the old version better.  This one is only shorter because you 'skipped' a bit at the end.

Comment: @TaraB: I have no preference, so I edited to write my old argument.

Comment: Sorry for all the comment mess.  Also +1. =]