# Unprovability of $i^2 =1$ from $\langle i \mid i^4 =1\rangle$ and similar problems

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

This question is related to [Can I derive $i^2 \neq 1$ from a presentation $\langle i, j \mid i^4 = j^4 = 1, ij = j^3 i\rangle$ of Quaternion group $Q$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424991/can-i-derive-i2-neq-1-from-a-presentation-langle-i-j-mid-i4-j4-1/425017?noredirect=1#425017)

I know I'm going too far but let me just ask...

1) Is indeed $\langle i \mid i^4 =1\rangle$ a presentation for the cyclic group of order 4?

2) If so, then do we just assume that $i^2 =1$ or should we prove that $i^2 =1$ cannot be derived from $i^4 =1$, i.e., the unprovability of $i^2 =1$ from $i^4=1$?

For the below questions I need answers only if the latter is the case in the above question 2.

3) Then how do we rigorously prove the unprovability?

4) As for 
$$\langle i, j \mid i^4 = j^4 = 1, ij = j^3 i\rangle = Q
$$
(Quaternion group), how do I prove unprovability of $i^2 =1$ from the given presentation? Or how do I even guess that $i^2 \neq 1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) yes.

2) can't be derived because there is a model for $i^4=1$ in which $i^2\ne1$, namely, $\{{1,\sqrt{-1},-1,-\sqrt{-1}\}}$.

3) See 2).

4) again, by constructing a model in which $i^2\ne1$. One way is by giving the group table for the quaternions.

Comment: Oh this is great. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

All points in @Gerry's answer are covering the cases completely, but just a point about $4$. Let $i^2=1$ when $$\textbf{Q}_8=\langle i,j\mid i^4=1,j^4=1,ij=j^3i\rangle$$ so we are considering the following presentation: $$\langle i,j\mid i^4=1,j^4=1,ij=j^3i, i^2=1\rangle=\langle i,j\mid i^2=1,j^4=1,ij=j^3i\rangle$$ but if $i^2=1$ so $i=i^{-1}$ and since $j^4=1$ so $j^3=j^{-1}$ and therefore we have $$ij=j^3i\longrightarrow ij=j^{-1}i^{-1}\longrightarrow(ji)^2=1$$ This means that we get: $$\langle i,j\mid i^2=1,j^4=1,(ji)^2=1\rangle\cong\textbf{D}_8$$ But we know $$\textbf{D}_8\ncong \textbf{Q}_8$$

Comment: Provided that we in fact do know that the dihedral and quaternion groups are not the same, this is a good argument. But if someone is not familiar with both groups, it won't be convincing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks so much. Indeed, mine will be useless if the OP don't know that differences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Luckily.. I know D_8 is not Q_8. And the answer uses the given presentation for the dihedral group of order 4. It's just that I was looking for more logic-based proof without using group theory knowledges except only primitive ones. Anyway, your answer will be good in situations where we can facilitate the two conditions that you've used. THANKS!

Comment: @julypraise: Welcome. I am glad I could help you.

Comment: +1 Babak. I miss you! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Miss you too :( Busy these days cause of my proposal.